# Netbeans PHP require_once() problem

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm stumped!

In PHP in Netbeans (6.8), a project has two files, file1.php and file2.php

file1.php starts `require_once('file2.php');`  and I get

```
Warning: require_once(query_form.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\file1.php on line 3

Call Stack:
0.0741     322920   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\file1.php:0


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'file2.php' (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\file1.php on line 3

Call Stack:
0.0741     322920   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\file1.php:0
```

I tried `require_once('./file2.php');`  and `require_once('.\file2.php');`  since it is windows. I even added `C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\` to the projects include path and it shows up as such on the prject view and see file1.php and file2.php It doesn't show up on this error report, but possibly because Netbeans (or PHP ]) knows that `C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\ === .`

Any suggestions?  Btw, I am new to Netbeans, so it i sprobably something very obvious.

---

Here are the first few lines of code, as requested

```
<?php
require_once('query_form.php');

$user = 'root';
$password = '';

 if (ConnectToDefaultDatabase($user, $password) === False)
  {
    ....
```

File1 above is actually index.php (shown here)  and file2 is query_form - I just tried to simplify

---

Just out of curiosity - does the one who voted this down have the cojones to step forward and say why? I had a problem, I asked a question, it got solved, but along the way everyone who helped got +1 from me.

I don't really mind being voted down, just wondered why you didn't attempt to explain

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the actual PHP code (at the very least the require lines and a few other lines beyond). You'll notice that the `include_path='.` is there which means that it should find files automagically when they're in the same folder. Also check that the web user (i'm assuming the error comes when you're trying to server it via apache) can read all the directories & files for your project.

Comment: Sorry, "query_form" is actually "form2". I tried to simplify it and blew it.

Comment: +1 "It'd be helpful to see the actual PHP code (at the very least the require lines and a few other lines beyond)"  ...   done

Comment: "Also check that the web user (i'm assuming the error comes when you're trying to server it via apache) can read all the directories & files for your project" ... well, it can read the first one :-)  and all were created by NetBeans, but I checked all permissions and no problems (it's a windows system, so the worst I could do would be read-only, can't prevent writing, and, in any case, require_once() only reads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to run it outside Netbeans?
Are the files in the same directory ?
What is the `line 3` in file1.php (I ask because you have a warnig and a fatal error in the same line).

---

This should be a comment but I cannot use it yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Probably some toying around with the working directory somewhere.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/file2.php'));
```

And if that doesn't work, copy the filename from a filemanager window & insert that, you wouldn't be the first to have either stray characters or a nasty typo which for some reason always escapes detection :)

Comment: +1 for some good suggestions.  The dirname() made no difference, and when I copied the file2 into file1 it ran ok, so no stray characters.    Btw,  Netbeans has a menu option Run/Validate file - but it seems to be permanently greyed out - any ideas?